# Adding Google Play Services to gradle (Android Studio) does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I have the following problem:

I installed the `Google Play Services` library `v27.0.0` to my `SDK` in Android Studio.

After that I added the compile dependencie to `build.gradle` (app folder):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:27.0.0'
}
```

But when I try to sync the project with Gradle, i get this error message:

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:27.0.0
```

I don't know what to do...

Comment: try this version  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'

Comment: In the future, if someone is wondering what the 27.0.0 was about, it was the 'version number'. This is the number listed in the versions column in the SDK tools app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think version 27.0.0 exists the most recent version is 8.1.0

Comment: Yep , a nice api overview can be found here : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 3):

There is one trick you can use with any dependency.
You know the name of dependency, lets consider `com.google.android.gms:play-services:`

Firstly, you need to use this expression

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Note the plus sign. Than you click `Sync Now` to sync gradle. After that you will see that IDE suggests you not to use + sign.
But now you can use combination `Alt+Enter` and select `Replace with specific version`.
Now + sign will be replaced with the latest available version of this library.

Profit.